# Difference between interpolated map using IDW in ArcGIS and turfjs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, inverse-distance-weighted, turf

I did the interpolation from the same map using arcgis and the turf.js library, using the same parameters and points. Could anyone say why the difference?

**ArcGIS params**
[image]

**ArcGIS Map**
[image]

**Turf.js params**

```
turf.interpolate(points, 20, {
  gridType: 'square',
  property: 'Ca_1',
  units: 'meters',
  weight: 1,
});
```

**Turf.js Map**
[image]

Comment: Most likely is number of points they are using by default.

Answer (score 1):

@felixIP - I agree, first check would be default number of points needed to make an estimation. In ArcMap you can assign the minimum number of samples needed to conduct the calculation.
Second check would be the search radius used by the interpolant to "look" for other data. It is not clear to me in the turfs documentation for interpolation (https://turfjs.org/docs/#interpolate) if they consider search radius and minimum number of samples - two very important variables that will dictate the interpolation.